# Unable to switch between dialogs in Bot Framework v4

Tags: botframework

I'm having some trouble moving around from one dialog to another in Bot Framework v4. What I want to accomplish is to move from say, dialog X to Y and then from Y back to X.

So for instance, I have a *GetShoppingCart* dialog and I want to switch to the *FindRecipe* dialog. I've tried adding the *FindRecipe* dialog 
(`dc.Dialogs.Add(FindRecipeDialog.Id, recipe_dialog);`) to the *GetShoppingCart's* waterfall, but as soon as I do the same thing in the *FindRecipe* dialog, there's an infinite loop.
This is troublesome since I need to add this line in order to access the dialog's destination id. Otherwise it will not be recongized when called by the Replace method (`await dc.Replace(FindRecipeDialog.Id, dialogArgs);`).

I then tried to pass the dialogs object from the root dialog to both *FindRecipe* and *GetShoppingCart* dialogs and did the following in the *GetShoppingCart* dialog:

```
IDialog recipe_dialog = dialogs.Find(FindRecipeDialog.Id);
dc.Dialogs.Add(FindRecipeDialog.Id, recipe_dialog);
await dc.Replace(FindRecipeDialog.Id, dialogArgs);
```

With this I was able to successfully enter the *FindRecipe* dialog, without creating the infinite loop.
In the *FindRecipe* dialog it performs the first watterfall step:

```
async(dc, args, next) =>
{
    UserStateObject newUserStateObject;
    var userState = UserState<UserState>.Get(dc.Context);
    UserStateObject userStateObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserStateObject>(userState.UserStateObject);
    if (args == null) {
        await FindRecipe(dc);
    } else {
        newUserStateObject = args["userState"] as UserStateObject;
        if(newUserStateObject.UserInputs.UserRecipeChoices == RecipeUserChoicesEnum.AddAnotherProductChoice) 
            await AddOtherProductChoice(dc, userStateObject);
    }
}
```

However, right after finishing just one method, it goes back to the *GetShoppingCart* dialog, even though there are still waterfall steps left in the *FindRecipe* dialog. In the following turn it throws this exception, when trying to perform "context.Continue()";

```
{System.Exception: DialogSet.continue(): Can't continue dialog. A dialog with an id of 'FindRecipe' wasn't found.   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogContext.Continue()   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogContainer.DialogContinue(DialogContext dc)   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogContext.Continue()   at RecipeBot.RecipesBot.OnTurn(ITurnContext context) ... }
```

Do I need to add the *FindRecipe* dialog to dc.Dialogs again at some point?

I've tried it right before dc.continue() (where the exception is thrown), but in this case it throws:

```
{System.Exception: DialogSet.add(): A dialog with an id of 'FindRecipe' already added.   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogSet.Add(String dialogId, IDialog dialog)   at RecipeBot.RecipesBot.OnTurn(ITurnContext context) ... }
```

Comment: `after finishing just one method, it goes back to the GetShoppingCart dialog, even though there are still waterfall steps left in the FindRecipe dialog.` If you can provide a reproducible sample or your complete implementation, we will test and troubleshoot issue with your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to fix this problem.

I was creating a new dialogue every time a message was received and this was causing the problem:

```
 dialogs = new DialogSet();
 dialogs.Add(GetShoppingCartDialog.Id, new GetShoppingCartDialog());
 dialogs.Add(FindRecipeDialog.Id, new FindRecipeDialog());
```

To fix it I used a singleton: created an instance of each dialog and saved it as a variable of the dialog.

```
 dialogs = new DialogSet();
 dialogs.Add(GetShoppingCartDialog.Id, GetShoppingCartDialog.Instance);
 dialogs.Add(FindRecipeDialog.Id, FindRecipeDialog.Instance);
```

Comment: am not seeing Dialogset.add method to have two parameters - only dialog is the parameter now